# Android locale currency symbol error

Tags: java, android, locale, currency

I'm trying get currency symbol based on where is user located (what language he have in smartphone). I'm using this code

```
String currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getSymbol();
```

On my phone Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime it works. I tested english(GB,US), german and slovak language. But when I run test on firebase testlab devices I got error

```
Unsupported ISO 3166 country: de
```

I was looking into methods in Locale and Currency and I found

```
Locale.getDefault().getVariant() + "  " + Locale.getDefault().getCountry()
```

this code return on my smartphone in Slovak language `"   SK"` and in German language `"   DE"` but on firebase devices it returns `"     "` nothing. And

```
Currency.getInstance
```

is using `locale.getCountry()` to determine country.

Thanks you any answers.

Comment: I have answered this question over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45354577/6565361