# Instrumentation test failed on Test Lab, bad currency symbol

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use Firebase Test Lab to run instrumentation tests of my Android app but some tests failed because the currency symbol is not euro (`€`) but the standard currency sign (`¤`).

The locale is well defined (French) and it works without problem on my local machine.

Am I supposed to not hard-write the `€` symbol in the test class and get it dynamically with `Currency` class ? But the good practise is to always hard-write the expected value...

```
Expected: with text: is "0,00 €"
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296465, res-name=total, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1071, height=57, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@120f8796, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=0,00 ¤, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Comment: A bit more context would be great. How is the text for the text view created (e.g. code snippet)? What locale are you setting in Test Lab? Just "French [fr]" or one with a country code like "French (France) [fr_FR]"? There's a similar question that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376439/locale-getdefault-returns-unsuported-invalid-locale-for-currency-getinstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one can pass the desired locale to test-lab with the `--device` parameter.

as the documentation for [gcloud firebase test android run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--device) reads:

> `--device` is now the preferred way to specify test devices and may not be used in conjunction with `--devices-ids`, `--os-version-ids`, `--locales`, or `--orientations`. Omitting all of the preceding dimension-related flags will run tests against a single device using defaults for all four device dimensions.

```
--device model=shamu,version=23,locale=fr_FR,orientation=default
```

else it will just use the default locale `en` - which results in that `¤` unspecified currency symbol.

to assume that French locale means the `€` as currency symbol might be wrongful; because when running `gcloud firebase test android locales list`, it outputs quite a bunch of the colonies:

```
│ fr     │ French                      │                                          
│ fr_BE  │ French                      │ Belgium                           
│ fr_BF  │ French                      │ Burkina Faso                      
│ fr_BI  │ French                      │ Burundi                           
│ fr_BJ  │ French                      │ Benin                             
│ fr_BL  │ French                      │ Saint Barthélemy                  
│ fr_CA  │ French                      │ Canada                            
│ fr_CD  │ French                      │ Congo (DRC)                       
│ fr_CF  │ French                      │ Central African Republic          
│ fr_CG  │ French                      │ Congo (Republic)                  
│ fr_CH  │ French                      │ Switzerland                       
│ fr_CI  │ French                      │ Côte d’Ivoire                     
│ fr_CM  │ French                      │ Cameroon                          
│ fr_DJ  │ French                      │ Djibouti                          
│ fr_DZ  │ French                      │ Algeria                           
│ fr_FR  │ French                      │ France                            
│ fr_GA  │ French                      │ Gabon                             
│ fr_GF  │ French                      │ French Guiana                     
│ fr_GN  │ French                      │ Guinea                            
│ fr_GP  │ French                      │ Guadeloupe                        
│ fr_GQ  │ French                      │ Equatorial Guinea                 
│ fr_HT  │ French                      │ Haiti                             
│ fr_KM  │ French                      │ Comoros                           
│ fr_LU  │ French                      │ Luxembourg                        
│ fr_MA  │ French                      │ Morocco                           
│ fr_MC  │ French                      │ Monaco                            
│ fr_MF  │ French                      │ Saint Martin                      
│ fr_MG  │ French                      │ Madagascar                        
│ fr_ML  │ French                      │ Mali                              
│ fr_MQ  │ French                      │ Martinique                        
│ fr_MR  │ French                      │ Mauritania                        
│ fr_MU  │ French                      │ Mauritius                         
│ fr_NC  │ French                      │ New Caledonia                     
│ fr_NE  │ French                      │ Niger                             
│ fr_PF  │ French                      │ French Polynesia                  
│ fr_PM  │ French                      │ Saint Pierre and Miquelon         
│ fr_RE  │ French                      │ Réunion                           
│ fr_RW  │ French                      │ Rwanda                            
│ fr_SC  │ French                      │ Seychelles                        
│ fr_SN  │ French                      │ Senegal                           
│ fr_SY  │ French                      │ Syria                             
│ fr_TD  │ French                      │ Chad                              
│ fr_TG  │ French                      │ Togo                              
│ fr_TN  │ French                      │ Tunisia                           
│ fr_VU  │ French                      │ Vanuatu                           
│ fr_WF  │ French                      │ Wallis and Futuna                 
│ fr_YT  │ French                      │ Mayotte
```

Comment: Yes I used "fr" instead of "fr_FR". Thanks a lot !

Comment: @woprandi `en` and `fr` only indicate the language - not the location... for some languages there might only be a single one currency symbol, but when it comes to languages with global distribution, displaying the unspecified `¤` only makes sense.

Comment: yeah I know, I don't know why I didn't find myself but the Test Lab examples use "en" and "fr"